# Android app crashing when opening a camera content

Tags: android, camera

I am writing an app where a button is pressed it must open the camera. But my apps keeps crashing on my `Nexus 5` running `Android 6.01` . 
Here is my onCLick Listener.

```
public void capturePhoto(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Capture button pressed.");
    Intent cameraApplicationIntent = new Intent();
    cameraApplicationIntent.setAction(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    cameraApplicationIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
    startActivityForResult(cameraApplicationIntent, CAMERA_INTENT_REQUEST);
}
```

I have these in the manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Here is my stacktrace and line 161 is 
`cameraApplicationIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));` :

```
01-24 01:42:50.859  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice D/ImageAcquisition﹕ Capture button pressed.
01-24 01:42:50.873  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1004)
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ at kiam.cameraintentpractice.ImageAcquisition.createImageFile(ImageAcquisition.java:197)
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ at kiam.cameraintentpractice.ImageAcquisition.capturePhoto(ImageAcquisition.java:157)
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4453)
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:932)
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice W/System.err﹕ ... 14 more
01-24 01:42:50.874  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
01-24 01:42:50.876  26744-26744/kiam.cameraintentpractice E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: kiam.cameraintentpractice, PID: 26744
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
            at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4458)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4453)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: file
            at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:452)
            at kiam.cameraintentpractice.ImageAcquisition.capturePhoto(ImageAcquisition.java:161)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4453)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Stacktrace please. and note that you require run time permission from user on marshmallow

Comment: Use this lib for android 6.0 https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions

Answer (score 0):

Simply having permission in manifest isn't enough in Android 6.0 and up. You need to request permissions at runtime :)

Docs:
http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html